# How did these characters do this at the end of the series?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

At the end of the Wheel of Time, something happens that is largely unexplained.  In the Epilogue, it is reveald that

> Rand and Moridin switch bodies.

How did this actually happen?

Answer (score 4):

At the end of A Crown of Swords, Rand follows Sammael to Shadar Logoth to kill him.  While he is there, he is helped by a mysterious stranger - this is Moridin.  At one point, Mashadar reaches for them, and they balefire Mashadar at the same time, crossing the streams.  This created some kind of bond between their souls.  From this point forward, several things start to happen:

- Rand starts to get his channeling sickness, causing nausea and double vision when he takes hold of or releases the Source.  When this happens he sees a face, and it becomes clearer with time.
- He starts to see the face in his dreams too, and Lews Therin starts talking about the "other one" occasionally.
- In Towers of Midnight, Moridin's hand seems to be stiff - he seems to be suffering some effects from Rand losing his hand, and Rand and Moridin also share a dream.
- Rand starts wearing a lot more red and black, Moridin's colors.

They definitely switched bodies because of this connection.  It seems most likely to me that since Moridin died at Shayol Ghul, Rand was then able move into his vacant body.

Comment: Didn't it also have something to do with the flaw in Callandor?